# gcc creates crashing code depending on optimisation

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have a rather complex multithreaded code, which I compile using gcc 4.8.1. When compiling with

```
g++ -c file.cc -march=native -mfpmath=sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4
--param inline-unit-growth=50 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self
-O2 -fPIC -funroll-loops -fforce-addr -rdynamic
```

the code produced crashes with segfault (which I was unable to debug, but the address of a struct all of a sudden differs from what it was when constructed, in particular, is no longer aligned to 32bytes as required by the code but only to 8bytes).

When compiling with `-O1` instead, the code works fine. I then added all the optimisation flags that make the difference between `-O1` and `-O2`. (To this end, I created two files `O1-opts` and `O2-opts` via

```
g++ -march=native -mfpmath=sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4
--param inline-unit-growth=50 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self
-O1 -fPIC -funroll-loops -fforce-addr -rdynamic
-Q --help=optimizers > O1-opts

g++ -march=native -mfpmath=sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4
--param inline-unit-growth=50 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Winit-self
-O2 -fPIC -funroll-loops -fforce-addr -rdynamic
-Q --help=optimizers > O2-opts
```

when `diff O1-opts O2-opts` provides the option differences). When adding *all* the option differences to `-O1`, the code generated still does not crash. This puzzles me. So my question is: shouldn't this give *exactly* the same result as with `-O2`? (and also: what is the likely cause of my problem?)

Comment: Crashing depending on optimization level sounds like undefined behavior but we don't have enough information.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I know, but that was not the main question.

Comment: @Walter which is probably why he answered your secondary question in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I have tried similar experiments without success and the best guess I have is that the documented flags do not fully cover the differences.

Comment: As always: Give a newer GCC like 4.9 or 5 a try. Maybe they fixed the problem and then you know it was a compiler bug. Additionally you can use sanitizers, I am amazed how ofter they give me useful hints.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is, by definition, not guaranteed to give *exactly the same results* from one compilation to another regardless of flags used. Or even from one run of the program to the next *even without* recompiling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC: Whats the difference between -O3 and -O2 + x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454415/gcc-whats-the-difference-between-o3-and-o2-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the `-O2` option not only sets different flags, but also enables additional optimizations in contrast to `-O1`.

The FAQ section of the GCC Wiki has an appropriate entry for [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#optimization-options).